# How to deserialize HashMaps in CXF

Tags: java, cxf, cxfrs

I have a service which returns a HashMap, and I am using org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider as my json provider, but I get error "No message body writer has been found for class java.util.Collections$EmptyMap, ContentType: application/json". How can I fix this ?

Comment: May be you have to update the JSONProivder or custom JSONProvider to return a Colleaction/Map.

Comment: Can we see your cxf configuration and which json provider you are using?